# Как применить ресурсы к одному элементу WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, usercontrol, resources

У меня есть главное окно на котором есть TabControl, к нему мне нужно приметить скачанные ресурсы.
Я пытаюсь сделать это так:

```
<Window x:Class="Frontend.View.AllWindows.MainWindow"       
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:cview="clr-namespace:Frontend.View.Controls.MainMenu"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
        xmlns:hc="https://handyorg.github.io/handycontrol"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="xProject"
        Height="450"
        Width="800"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        WindowStyle="ThreeDBorderWindow"
        Background="Gray">

    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/HandyControl;component/Themes/SkinDefault.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/HandyControl;component/Themes/Theme.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <hc:TabControl>
            <hc:TabItem Header="Console">
                <cview:ConsoleControl/>
            </hc:TabItem>

            <hc:TabItem Header="User">
                <cview:UserPageControl/>
            </hc:TabItem>

            <hc:TabItem Header="Chat">
                <cview:ChatControl/>
            </hc:TabItem>
        </hc:TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Но таким способом все дочерние элементы окна тоже применяют на себя эти ресурсы. Как я могу это исправить?

Comment: Что исправить? Вы подключили тему в ресурсах окна, она применяется ко всему окну. А надо как? Если только для табконтрола, то делайте это в ресурсах табконтрола.

Comment: можно назначить x:key словарю ресурсов и подключать по ключу к нужным контролам.